# SQL query example

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables `users` (id, name), `types` (id, name) and `user_type` (users_id, types_id)

I would like to write a SQL query that gets all the users that DO NOT have a type. I know this is probably easy but I can't get my head around it.

Any help

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT users.name
FROM users JOIN user_types ON users.id = user_types.users_id
WHERE user_types.types_id != yourID
```

Comment: It should work as intended with just the join and no WHERE clause.

Comment: It will not work without the WHERE clause unless you use a compound condition. Without the WHERE clause, it will return all users that are in both tables regardless of the type.

Comment: user_types its many to many relation, if for example: user with id `1` have type `2` and `3` and you whant to filter users with no type 3. Im not shure this query work...

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE users_id NOT IN
    (SELECT users_id FROM user_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE users_id NOT IN (SELECT users_id FROM user_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative you can use `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_type WHERE users.USER_ID = user_type.USER_ID)
```

another alternative is to use left join and check nulls

```
SELECT *
FROM users AS s
LEFT JOIN user_type AS ut
ON s.USER_ID = ut.user_id
WHERE ut.USER_ID IS null
```

Documentation on `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` can be found here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html